# How to use NetTcpBinding in code?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, tcp

**Not a duplicate!** - The suggested duplicate deals with `one using netTcpBinding and one using mexTcpBinding`. **Read on to see that that is not the case here:**

Here's my code:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(class1Type, new Uri(uri));
host.AddServiceEndpoint(interface1Type, new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None), uri);
host.Open();
```

I have made a copy of the project and am running two instances with one difference - the last character in the uri string. There is nothing in the configuration file. All is in code.

The uri is of the form:
`net.tcp://localhost/abc/def`

I'm getting an error:

> There is already a listener on IP endpoint 0.0.0.0:808. This could
>   happen if there is another application already listening on this
>   endpoint or if you have multiple service endpoints in your service
>   host with the same IP endpoint but with incompatible binding
>   configurations.

I don’t understand this error, both services are the same, so how can they be incompatible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [There is already a listener on IP endpoint 0.0.0.0:13000. ?? (TCP using WCF)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744683/there-is-already-a-listener-on-ip-endpoint-0-0-0-013000-tcp-using-wcf)

Comment: @AllanElder My question specifically says: "in code". But thanks.

Comment: Your services should use different ports

Comment: nettcp can handle multiple services on one port. "port sharing".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I was missing was:

```
PortSharingEnabled = true
```

(I don't think the error message is clear enough.)