# WCF - There is already a listener on IP endpoint 0.0.0.0:808x

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

This works fine with C# 4 in Visual studio 2010, but stops working in Visual Studio 2015 with same framework setting. I just created a new Visual studio solution to change my IDE.

I have already come across these link - And did solve this problem in another project facing same issue but on .Net framework 4.5 and Visual Studio 2015.

[There is already a listener on IP endpoint 0.0.0.0:13000. ?? (TCP using WCF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744683/there-is-already-a-listener-on-ip-endpoint-0-0-0-013000-tcp-using-wcf)

Can't understand why would 4.0 framework target WCF project won't run in VS 2015, but would run fine in VS 2010.

Has anyone else faced same problem, and solved it.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked any other application hosted in the port?

Comment: Yes, nothing existing using webservice ports. Also the fact that only thing different is new solution is vs2015, when I run the old solution in vs2010 everything runs good as expected. So point is why would debugging same project with 2015 will have this issue but not while debugging in vs2010.